# Call to cuMemcpyDtoH results in UNKNOWN_CUDA_ERROR

Tags: python-3.x, cuda

I am trying to play with [this code](https://github.com/harrism/numba_examples/blob/master/mandelbrot_numba.ipynb), the last part with CUDA python.

The example given is working fine however when I set bigger dimensions I get this error :

```
C:\Users\Lichar\Nextcloud\python\Fractal>python3 CUDA_Example.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CUDA_Example.py", line 57, in <module>
    d_image.to_host()
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\numba\cuda\cudadrv\devicearray.py", line 217, in to_host
    self.copy_to_host(self.__writeback, stream=stream)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\numba\cuda\cudadrv\devicearray.py", line 200, in copy_to_host
    _driver.device_to_host(hostary, self, self.alloc_size, stream=stream)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\numba\cuda\cudadrv\driver.py", line 1606, in device_to_host
    fn(host_pointer(dst), device_pointer(src), size, *varargs)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\numba\cuda\cudadrv\driver.py", line 288, in safe_cuda_api_call
    self._check_error(fname, retcode)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\numba\cuda\cudadrv\driver.py", line 323, in _check_error
    raise CudaAPIError(retcode, msg)
numba.cuda.cudadrv.driver.CudaAPIError: [719] Call to cuMemcpyDtoH results in UNKNOWN_CUDA_ERROR
```

A 8500*8500 image works fine but a 10000*10000 image raises the error. I guess the array I'm passing is too "big" but I can't understand why. Here are the details of my gpu :

```
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\extras\demo_suite>deviceQuery
deviceQuery Starting...

 CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

Detected 1 CUDA Capable device(s)

Device 0: "GeForce GTX 1070"
  CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          9.1 / 9.0
  CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    6.1
  Total amount of global memory:                 8192 MBytes (8589934592 bytes)
  (15) Multiprocessors, (128) CUDA Cores/MP:     1920 CUDA Cores
  GPU Max Clock rate:                            1772 MHz (1.77 GHz)
  Memory Clock rate:                             4004 Mhz
  Memory Bus Width:                              256-bit
  L2 Cache Size:                                 2097152 bytes
  Maximum Texture Dimension Size (x,y,z)         1D=(131072), 2D=(131072, 65536), 3D=(16384, 16384, 16384)
  Maximum Layered 1D Texture Size, (num) layers  1D=(32768), 2048 layers
  Maximum Layered 2D Texture Size, (num) layers  2D=(32768, 32768), 2048 layers
  Total amount of constant memory:               65536 bytes
  Total amount of shared memory per block:       49152 bytes
  Total number of registers available per block: 65536
  Warp size:                                     32
  Maximum number of threads per multiprocessor:  2048
  Maximum number of threads per block:           1024
  Max dimension size of a thread block (x,y,z): (1024, 1024, 64)
  Max dimension size of a grid size    (x,y,z): (2147483647, 65535, 65535)
  Maximum memory pitch:                          2147483647 bytes
  Texture alignment:                             512 bytes
  Concurrent copy and kernel execution:          Yes with 2 copy engine(s)
  Run time limit on kernels:                     Yes
  Integrated GPU sharing Host Memory:            No
  Support host page-locked memory mapping:       Yes
  Alignment requirement for Surfaces:            Yes
  Device has ECC support:                        Disabled
  CUDA Device Driver Mode (TCC or WDDM):         WDDM (Windows Display Driver Model)
  Device supports Unified Addressing (UVA):      Yes
  Device PCI Domain ID / Bus ID / location ID:   0 / 1 / 0
  Compute Mode:
     < Default (multiple host threads can use ::cudaSetDevice() with device simultaneously) >

deviceQuery, CUDA Driver = CUDART, CUDA Driver Version = 9.1, CUDA Runtime Version = 9.0, NumDevs = 1, Device0
= GeForce GTX 1070
Result = PASS
```

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46017846/cuda-api-error-on-python-with-numba) but didn't understand how to apply it to my case.

**How should I properly configure the `griddim` and `blockdim` variables ?** (Guess (128, 8) is the maximum block dim for me)

**What causes that error and how to avoid it without cutting the image in different parts ?**

Thanks

**UPDATE :**

If I change the max iteration from 1000 to 100, there isn't any error anymore.

Comment: If you are running on a display GPU, you are probably hitting the driver watchdog time limit at large sizes because your code is taking too long to run.

Comment: I'm indeed running it on the GPU that displays everything. However the 8000px image run in 2.05 seconds

Comment: I enabled the integrated intel HD graphics in BIOS, switch to it on windows and ran the code again but same error. I think it is something else although I will encounter this problem whenever I will generate huge images (which is my goal). I'v read 5s can be the limit.

Comment: That won't change anything. If the GPU is using he WDDM driver, it has a timeout, whether it is actually the primary display card or not

Comment: Wouldn't it display a timeout error ? Not something that seems related to the memory ?

Comment: You are very likely hitting the display timeout limit.  The error reported in this situation can vary.

Comment: How can I bypass this limitation ?

Comment: do a bit of research.  This topic is covered extensively.  Google "cuda wddm tdr"

Comment: Looks like you solved my problem. Last question, how bad it is to set a huge limite ? (although I'll remove it after processing my images)